# How do I send signed emails from ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rsa, actionmailer

I'm using GMail as my SMTP server. I have that configuration working just fine:

```
# config/initializers/action_mailer.rb:
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :tls            => true,
  :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port           => "587",
  :domain         => "www.example.org",
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name      => "admin@example.org",
  :password       => "it's a secret"
}
```

I also have a public/private RSA key pair in `config/ssl/rsa.public` and `config/ssl/rsa.private`.

What do I do to sign the emails before shipping them off to GMail's SMTP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [ActionmailerX509](http://github.com/penso/actionmailer_x509). You need a certificate which you can a) buy for lots of money b) get for free from CAcert.org c) generate yourself. Everything you need to know is explained in the README.