# How do I send signed emails from ActionMailer in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, x509

Using Rails 3 I want to use an X.509 certificate to sign parts of emails. There is a currently existing answer for Rails 2 at [How do I send signed emails from ActionMailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684726/how-do-i-send-signed-emails-from-actionmailer) but it doesn't work on Rails 3.

Is it possible to sign emails via ActionMailer in Rails 3?
If that is not possible, is it possible to sign emails via sendmail after creating by ActionMailer?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work on Rails 3" what exactly do you mean - what errors are you seeing?  The plugin is tested only on Rails 2.0.1 but the code in https://github.com/penso/actionmailer_x509/blob/master/lib/actionmailer_x509.rb should still work.

Comment: I get such error `undefined method 'create!' for class 'ActionMailer::Base' (NameError)` in `vendor/plugins/actionmailer_x509/lib/actionmailer_x509.rb:80:in '<class:Base>'`

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/penso/actionmailer_x509/issues/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been ported actionmailer_x509 to Rails 3 and wrap it into the gem. So now it works and available here: https://github.com/petRUShka/actionmailer_x509

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it's not the best answer, however here's what I'd do:

- try to install that plugin (even if it's for rails 2.0.x)
- tests and fix code until I get the result

looking at the code, turns out that the core file is:

https://github.com/penso/actionmailer_x509/blob/master/lib/actionmailer_x509.rb

which exposes a bunch of methods for mailer DSL:

- x509_sign   true # or false
- x509_cert   "path/to/cert"
- x509_key    "path/to/key"
- x509_passphrase  "passphrase"

so you could grab that file, and put it under $APP/lib, then write some test to check it's working.

A.

Comment: All of that don't work :( I have ported this plugin to Rails 3. The problem is that the plugin don't work even under 2.0.1: https://github.com/penso/actionmailer_x509/issues/2 :( I will try to fix it in my fork: https://github.com/petRUShka/actionmailer_x509

Comment: I know it doesn't work. what I was saying is to fix that code until it works. I've also suggested to grab just the main lib file, because it's the core of that plugin. perhaps, all you need to do is a porting to the new ActionMailer API

Comment: I have done ported to new ActionMailer API. But may be openssl have changed since 2008 because main test in actionmailer_x509 testsuite is broken now (in my Rails 3 port and in new rvm gemset with Rails 2.0.1)

Comment: maybe you're using them in the wrong way, X509 is a standard. check if you have done all the necessary steps to setup certs.

Comment: I have some trouble with porting. Original approach that was used with Tmail gem don't work with new Mail gem. It would be great if you can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663409/ruby-mail-gem-add-r-n-after-60-chars-in-mail