# Ruby: Mail gem add \r\n after 60 chars in mail

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, rubygems, actionmailer

I want to port [actionmailer_x509](https://github.com/petRUShka/actionmailer_x509) to Rails 3. In order to do that I try to create Mail object from big string with signed email.

You can see such creation on this line: https://github.com/petRUShka/actionmailer_x509/blob/master/lib/actionmailer_x509.rb#L129

Original string (*smime0*): https://gist.github.com/1d2c84cc2e255be010a6

Resulted Mail object dumped to file(*newm*): https://gist.github.com/4682fe88e8dcfeca60b2

For example, you can see the difference between line 26 of *smime0* and line 40 of *newm*. In *smime0* `\r\n` is setted after each 64 chars, and in *newm* `\r\n` is setted after each 60 chars.

Such behaviour brokes signature. Is it possible to change this behaviour? I tried to find out how to turn off it, but was failed.

May be there is some other workaround for this point.

P.S. Mail gem: https://github.com/mikel/mail, thread with discussion about x509 and actionmailer: [How do I send signed emails from ActionMailer in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428983/how-do-i-send-signed-emails-from-actionmailer-in-rails-3/6890090#6890090)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The carriage returns shouldn't be a problem, because the parser will know that it's base64 encoded (and will discard `\r\n`).

I think the error comes from the [Content-id](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/fields/content_id_field.rb#L25). I see that in your mail samples, newm adds a Content-ID field, and it changes the signed message (try to remove the Content-ID line and verify the message).

Possible workarounds:

- Fix the Mail gem to prevent it from adding a Content-ID
- Add a Content-ID before signing, because Mail will keep it if it's present

Comment: It seems to be true. I will check it!